# How to update tables with one-to-many relationship?

Tags: database

I have two tables, Class and Student, which are with one-to-many relationship. It's simple to add a Class since I just need to provide the essential data for a Class and for multiple Student, and deleting is easier.

But when I want to update a Class, problem comes. For updating, besides the changed attributes of Class itself, there may be some actions like addition, modification and deletion on Student. How should I organize the data to give all the potential information to make a updating appropriately?

After I searching on the Internet, I got a solution to solve the above issue: combine deleting with adding to simulate updating. That does work, and also is very simple. But frequently adding and deleting records may result in two problems: ineffeciency and size-limitation of auto-incremental primary key.

So I wonder is there a better(or typical) way to solve my problem? Or If I adopt the above solution, how to avoid the side effect, especially the size-limitation of auto-incremental primary key?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In a typical application, you don't update a class and its students in one go. You update a class, or add a student, or remove a student, but not everything at once.

Even if you had to do it, the solution would depend on the architecture of your app, on the framework used to access the database, etc., so it's hard to give a definitive answer. For example, using JPA or Hibernate, you could modify the whole tree of objects, and merge it, and everything would be automatically handled.

If you have to do it by yourself, you could simply send the updated class with the updated students. You would first update the class's own information. then loop to the students and update their own information. Then see which students are currently in the class (in the database), and which ones are in the sent students, and remove the ones that have disappeared.

Deleting students and recreating them is not an option, most of the time, not because it's inefficient or because you would exhaust the IDs (long goes to 2^63, which is huge), but because you probably have other tables with forign keys pointing to the students to update.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. I know what you mean, and agree with your opinion very much. Actually, my above requirement is originated from another problem: how to build another database (called A) to store the varying information of one database(called B) for committing in furture. When B has been designed, how to effectively design tables in A based on B's architecture? Any suggestions?